# Why the syncing of the wallet is very very slow?

Tags: synchronization

I am new in Monero, I created a wallet address with Monero GUI, and someone transferred a little bit Monero to my address. However, I cannot see any transferred Monero in my wallet and the wallet just shows me a message about daemon syncing, after a week there is still 250000 daemon blocks to synchronize?!!! I really do not understand whether it is normal for the all wallets? Or there is a problem with my wallet?

Comment: Do you have a spinning HD or SSD?

Comment: I have SSD in Macpro

Comment: What version of the GUI are you running?

Answer (score 1):

The Blockchain is huge. If you don't have a very high speed internet connexion, it's usual do need a week and a half to download the 55G Blockchain in a peer-to-peer manner with monerod.
Mine took that time to download.

Comment: Wow! It does not make Monero impractical?

Comment: If you cannot afford hosting your own node because the blockchain is too big, then you can just connect to a remote node. But after initial sync is done, it runs very well.

Comment: What kind of hard disk do you have ? An old spinny molass ? A week is crazy...